# [UITableView _contentOffsetForScrollingToRowAtIndexPath:atScrollPosition:]

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uitableview

I am using a tableview to display a message and i used the code below

```
UIView *chatView = [self bubbleView:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", message] from:YES];

[self.chatArray addObject:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:message, @"text", @"self", @"speaker", chatView, @"view", nil]];
[self.chatTableView reloadData];

[self.chatTableView scrollToRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:[self.chatArray count]-1 inSection:0]
                                atScrollPosition: UITableViewScrollPositionBottom
                                animated:YES];
```

And i am getting the error given below

```
[UITableView _contentOffsetForScrollingToRowAtIndexPath:atScrollPosition:]: row (0) beyond bounds (0) for section (0).'
```

plz help me in solving this

Comment: Maybe set `[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:[self.chatArray count]-1 inSection:0]` to a variable and check the value of it before calling `scrollToRowAtIndexPath`. make sure all values are what they're supposed to be

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Seems to me that your table view does not have any rows or sections in yet. Two possibilities come to my mind.

1. Check your `numberOfRowsInSection` delegate and `numberOfSectionsInTableView` so that they are not set to 0.
2. Its possible that the `tableview` has not yet finished loading the data.

Do share your findings, so I might be able to help out further if needed.

Comment: @vinoad what exactly did you do to fix that problem?

Comment: Well, his issue was that he was trying to perform operations on table view before it was properly set up i.e. it had any rows in it. So, I think he just changed that.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure your table view is getting reloaded before scrolling. because after adding the data in the array, we need to reload the data to populate the TableView cell.

Answer (score 0):

I got this problem when my tableView delegate and dataSource was mapped to another view controller. Make sure you haven't done the same.